# Get a file's character encoding without reading entire file into memory

Tags: php, file, character-encoding

I know if you need to get the character encoding of a file in PHP you can do

```
var_dump (mb_detect_encoding (file_get_contents ("somefile.txt")));
```

However, doing this with a big file is not very practical as it eats up a big chunk of memory.

Is there a way of determining the character encoding reliably without having to read the entire file into memory?

Comment: By its very nature, character encoding detection is imprefect at best. You can trivially change your code to read only, say, 65536 bytes max; but there is no guarantee that there isn't a game-changer in the remaining bytes.

Comment: In most scenarios, 64k should be plenty enough. If you go smaller, you increase the risk of false detections. For example, some text files have a boilerplate EULA header in English which exceeds 8k and the content after the ASCII-only header could be in any language, or a mixture of languages.

Comment: I've been reading on this, and it is possible to get a part from your file by using the file_get_contents so you don't have to load the entire file.. Ofc as tripleee said, the character encoding detetion is not a guarantee it is the right encoding..

Comment: http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2007/KimPark-AutomaticDetectionOfCharacterEncodingAndLanguages.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way of determining the character encoding reliably without having to read the whole file.

Reason: the character codes differing from ASCII (which is still a base part of many encodings) are randomly distributed in a file. They might by chance be all in the part you did not read.

Of course, some encodings are very easy to identify from the beginning, but this is not the question here.

(giving you the chance to accept an answer as solution, although the answer might have been given in a comment, what you should not do (SO policy).)

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use cache,
you can use function below that may help you for the same

ex:

output:
string(6) "Hello "
string(11) "Hello World"

some more functions:

PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE    ob_clean(), ob_end_clean(), and ob_get_clean().
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE    ob_end_flush(), ob_flush(), and ob_get_flush().
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE    ob_end_clean(), ob_end_flush(), and ob_get_flush().

for more info visit : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any meaningful way